# SQL's INNER JOIN resulting in duplicate entries even though there are no duplicate column values in all 3 tables

Tags: sql, inner-join

With regards to the first question on the URL: https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/movie-database-exercise/subqueries-exercises-on-movie-database.php#SQLEDITOR, "Write a query in SQL to list all the information of the actors who played a role in the movie 'Annie Hall'.", can anyone explain why the query below results in a duplicate entry even though there are no duplicate id column values in each of the 3 tables: `actor`, `movie_cast`, and `movie`?

SQL query:

```
SELECT actor.act_id, actor.act_fname, actor.act_lname, actor.act_gender
FROM actor
INNER JOIN movie_cast ON actor.act_id = movie_cast.act_id
INNER JOIN movie ON movie_cast.mov_id = movie.mov_id
WHERE movie.mov_title = 'Annie Hall'
```

The output of the above query on w3resource is:

```
act_id  act_fname   act_lname   act_gender
111 Woody   Allen   M
111 Woody   Allen   M
```

Samples of the 3 tables:

actor:

```
act_id |      act_fname       |      act_lname       | act_gender
--------+----------------------+----------------------+------------
    101 | James                | Stewart              | M
    102 | Deborah              | Kerr                 | F
    103 | Peter                | OToole               | M
    104 | Robert               | De Niro              | M
    105 | F. Murray            | Abraham              | M
    106 | Harrison             | Ford                 | M
    107 | Nicole               | Kidman               | F
    108 | Stephen              | Baldwin              | M
    109 | Jack                 | Nicholson            | M
    110 | Mark                 | Wahlberg             | M
    111 | Woody                | Allen                | M
    112 | Claire               | Danes                | F
    113 | Tim                  | Robbins              | M
    114 | Kevin                | Spacey               | M
    115 | Kate                 | Winslet              | F
    116 | Robin                | Williams             | M
    117 | Jon                  | Voight               | M
    118 | Ewan                 | McGregor             | M
    119 | Christian            | Bale                 | M
    120 | Maggie               | Gyllenhaal           | F
    121 | Dev                  | Patel                | M
    122 | Sigourney            | Weaver               | F
    123 | David                | Aston                | M
    124 | Ali                  | Astin                | F
```

movie_cast:

```
act_id | mov_id |              role
--------+--------+--------------------------------
    101 |    901 | John Scottie Ferguson
    102 |    902 | Miss Giddens
    103 |    903 | T.E. Lawrence
    104 |    904 | Michael
    105 |    905 | Antonio Salieri
    106 |    906 | Rick Deckard
    107 |    907 | Alice Harford
    108 |    908 | McManus
    110 |    910 | Eddie Adams
    111 |    911 | Alvy Singer
    112 |    912 | San
    113 |    913 | Andy Dufresne
    114 |    914 | Lester Burnham
    115 |    915 | Rose DeWitt Bukater
    116 |    916 | Sean Maguire
    117 |    917 | Ed
    118 |    918 | Renton
    120 |    920 | Elizabeth Darko
    121 |    921 | Older Jamal
    122 |    922 | Ripley
    114 |    923 | Bobby Darin
    109 |    909 | J.J. Gittes
    119 |    919 | Alfred Borden
```

movie:

```
 mov_id |                     mov_title                      | mov_year | mov_time |    mov_lang     | mov_dt_rel | mov_rel_country
--------+----------------------------------------------------+----------+----------+-----------------+------------+-----------------
    901 | Vertigo                                            |     1958 |      128 | English         | 1958-08-24 | UK
    902 | The Innocents                                      |     1961 |      100 | English         | 1962-02-19 | SW
    903 | Lawrence of Arabia                                 |     1962 |      216 | English         | 1962-12-11 | UK
    904 | The Deer Hunter                                    |     1978 |      183 | English         | 1979-03-08 | UK
    905 | Amadeus                                            |     1984 |      160 | English         | 1985-01-07 | UK
    906 | Blade Runner                                       |     1982 |      117 | English         | 1982-09-09 | UK
    907 | Eyes Wide Shut                                     |     1999 |      159 | English         |            | UK
    908 | The Usual Suspects                                 |     1995 |      106 | English         | 1995-08-25 | UK
    909 | Chinatown                                          |     1974 |      130 | English         | 1974-08-09 | UK
    910 | Boogie Nights                                      |     1997 |      155 | English         | 1998-02-16 | UK
    911 | Annie Hall                                         |     1977 |       93 | English         | 1977-04-20 | USA
    912 | Princess Mononoke                                  |     1997 |      134 | Japanese        | 2001-10-19 | UK
    913 | The Shawshank Redemption                           |     1994 |      142 | English         | 1995-02-17 | UK
    914 | American Beauty                                    |     1999 |      122 | English         |            | UK
    915 | Titanic                                            |     1997 |      194 | English         | 1998-01-23 | UK
    916 | Good Will Hunting                                  |     1997 |      126 | English         | 1998-06-03 | UK
    917 | Deliverance                                        |     1972 |      109 | English         | 1982-10-05 | UK
    918 | Trainspotting                                      |     1996 |       94 | English         | 1996-02-23 | UK
    919 | The Prestige                                       |     2006 |      130 | English         | 2006-11-10 | UK
    920 | Donnie Darko                                       |     2001 |      113 | English         |            | UK
    921 | Slumdog Millionaire                                |     2008 |      120 | English         | 2009-01-09 | UK
    922 | Aliens                                             |     1986 |      137 | English         | 1986-08-29 | UK
    923 | Beyond the Sea                                     |     2004 |      118 | English         | 2004-11-26 | UK
    924 | Avatar                                             |     2009 |      162 | English         | 2009-12-17 | UK
    926 | Seven Samurai                                      |     1954 |      207 | Japanese        | 1954-04-26 | JP
    927 | Spirited Away                                      |     2001 |      125 | Japanese        | 2003-09-12 | UK
    928 | Back to the Future                                 |     1985 |      116 | English         | 1985-12-04 | UK
    925 | Braveheart                                         |     1995 |      178 | English         | 1995-09-08 | UK
```

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Also, links die. Insert images/links using edit functions. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Explain what you expect but also why you expect it. Otherwise an answer is just, because that's how SQL is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your `movie_cast` table has duplicate entry for actor `Woody Allen`. You can check with below query. You can see the output in image below, so you are getting two records in your query. If you want to eliminate duplicate entry then try `DISTINCT` in your query.

```
SELECT *
FROM movie_cast
WHERE movie_cast.act_id = 111
```

[image]

Query with distinct records.

```
SELECT DISTINCT actor.act_id, actor.act_fname, actor.act_lname, actor.act_gender
FROM actor
INNER JOIN movie_cast ON actor.act_id = movie_cast.act_id
INNER JOIN movie ON movie_cast.mov_id = movie.mov_id
WHERE movie.mov_title = 'Annie Hall'
```

---

**OP's question from comment.**

> Why does the proposed solution not result in any duplicates though? Proposed Solution: SELECT * FROM actor WHERE act_id IN( SELECT act_id FROM movie_cast WHERE mov_id IN ( SELECT mov_id FROM movie WHERE mov_title='Annie Hall' ));

**Answer**

Because `inner query` will have list which will consist of duplicate `mov_id`. But `outer query` will only check once for each record whether `inner query` result consists `current` row's `mov_id` or not.

Comment: Thanks Karan! I was wondering how there could be duplicates in any of the 3 tables given that the 3 sample tables did not show any under the id columns. However, when I ```SELECT * FROM movie_cast ORDER BY act_id``` I realized that each distinct entry comes in pairs! Guess I did not take the "sample" word literally.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is usually the worst way of resolving duplicate rows, since people will tend to overuse it rather than getting to the root cause of the duplicates. However, in this case it's clear that the table is declared badly because there are no keys on the table and so you cannot use better tools for resolving the duplicate here

Comment: Why does the proposed solution not result in any duplicates though?

Proposed Solution:
```SELECT * 
FROM actor 
WHERE act_id IN(
SELECT act_id 
FROM movie_cast 
WHERE mov_id IN (
SELECT mov_id 
FROM movie 
WHERE mov_title='Annie Hall'
));```

Comment: I have updated my answer for your question. Please check

Comment: What are ```inner query``` and ```outer query``` in this case?

Comment: **Outer query** `SELECT * FROM actor WHERE act_id IN`. **Inner query** `SELECT act_id FROM movie_cast WHERE mov_id IN`. It has **Inner query** inside **inner query** `SELECT mov_id FROM movie WHERE mov_title='Annie Hall'`

Comment: So ```SELECT act_id FROM movie_cast WHERE mov_id IN ``` is an overlap between ```outer query``` and ```inner query```?

Comment: `IN` will be check like result values from `SELECT act_id FROM movie_cast WHERE mov_id IN` contains current row's `act_id`. If yes then it will select current row.

Comment: So for example, ```SELECT act_id FROM movie_cast WHERE mov_id IN``` yields 2 rows where ```act_id``` = ```111```, the ```outer query```, ```SELECT * FROM actor WHERE act_id IN``` will just choose the first occurrence/row where ```act_id``` = ```111```?